# Nuxt js middleware auth redirect authenticated user to login page

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm using **@nuxt/auth** package with version **4.9.1**.

Everything works properly before the user closes their browser, The problem arises when the user closes the browser after logging in and comes back with an absolute URL like this `example.com/admin`.

How this problem can be resolved?

**middleware/admin.js**

```
export default function ({$auth, error}) {
  if ($auth.user.type === 'admin') {
    return error('404 Not Found!')
  }
}
```

**pages/admin.index**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    {{ $auth.user.name || $auth.user.mobile_number }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name      : "admin",
    middleware: ['auth', 'admin'],
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `loggedIn` in your middleware when the user opens an absolute URL. (example.com/admin)

For more information : [auth#loggedin](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#loggedin)

Demo : [Nuxt-auth-demo](https://nuxt-auth.herokuapp.com) (`/secure` page needs authenticating to access. and after you logged in you can try to close your browser and open it again with absolute path `nuxt-auth.herokuapp.com/secure`.)

Comment: incorrect, when you close browser and re-open a secure page, nuxt redirect client to login page and after a second it know you are login ...